# How do I add margin-bottom to all elements with a class using each element's own height with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create an image overlay feature that pushes up images by half of their own height.

So far I've been able to adjust the CSS for all elements, but I'd like to add a marginBottom to each that's half of it's own height.

```
function adjustMarginBottom() {
    const x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

//I think this line should look something like this, but I'm still trying to work it out. 
    x[i].style.marginBottom = x[i].height - 50%;
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: "- 50%" is not math. I guess it is just: x[i].height * 0.5 Or as css value "calc(" + x[i].height + "px / 2)"

Answer (score 1):

Take a look:

```js
function marginBottom() {
  const x = document.querySelectorAll('.example');
  x.forEach(img => {
    const heightImg = img.height / 2;
    console.log(heightImg);
    img.style.marginBottom = `${heightImg}px`;
  });
}

window.addEventListener('load', marginBottom);
```

```html
<div>
    <img class="example" src="https://fakeimg.pl/250x100/ff0000/">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="example" src="https://fakeimg.pl/250x100/000/">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="example" src="https://fakeimg.pl/250x100/ececec/">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this

```
function adjustMarginBottom() {
    const x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.marginBottom = `${x[i].clientHeight / 2}px`;;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function adjustMarginBottom() {
    const x =document.getElementsByClassName("example");
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    
    str = x[i].style.marginBottom.slice(0, -2);
    //Outputs 5, in this case
    
    x[i].style.marginBottom=Number(str)+1+"px";
    //Add 10 margin bottom
        }
    }
```

```css
body{
background:#111111;
color:white;
}
.example{
background:#222222;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:adjustMarginBottom();">Add 1px to margin-bottom</a>

<div class="example" style="margin-bottom:5px;">this is some content...</div>

<div class="example" style="margin-bottom:5px;">this is some content...</div>

<div class="example" style="margin-bottom:5px;">this is some content...</div>
```